# Shifting elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays, stm32

I need a little help. I want to shift the elements in an array one element up, so that the new position 1 contains the old value from position 1, new-2 contains old-1, and so on. The old last value is discarded, and the new value of the first position is a new value that I give every second.

I use an array of size 10:

```
uint32_t TEST[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

The code that I use must be executed every second.

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    /* Code for shifting the elements */
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
    {                
       TEST[i+1] = TEST[i];
    }
    TEST[0] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
}
```

Comment: `i < 10` --> `i < 9`

Comment: a. Not sure what is the question you are asking.
b. You need to change the for loop and limit to `i < 9` because 9 + 1 is beyond the definition of TEST.

Comment: Just as a small hint its maybe better to use a ringbuffer. This can save a large amount of copy instructions. @BLUEPIXY Yes this should be the solution

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You need to loop from 9 downto 1 inclusive. Your loop as is is overwriting every element with the first element.

Answer (score 3):

Ringbuffer causes less copying of data, if you want last_pos to point to the freshest sample, you increase it before the read.

```
uint32_t TEST[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int last_pos = 0; /* init to any valid number between 0 and 9 inclusively */

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    last_pos = (last_pos + 1) % 10;
    TEST[last_pos] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If buffer must remain continuous, and ringbuffer won't do, then `memmove` is the simplest option:

```
memmove(&TEST[1], &TEST[0], count * sizeof(*TEST));
```

where:

- `&TEST[1]` is the destination of first element
- `&TEST[0]` is the first element to move
- `count` is the number of elements to move (now 9)
- `sizeof(*TEST)` is the size of single element

Alternative way of counting the number of bytes is `sizeof(TEST) - sizeof(*TEST)`, which will substract size of single element from the size of the entire array. However, this will only work when TEST is an actual array, and not an pointer (for example array passed as an argument to a function decayed into pointer).